# Using curl to request Chatgpt API on Windows Cmd

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

This is my command using Windonws Cmd:

```
curl -x 127.0.0.1:33210 https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions^
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" ^
  -H "Authorization: Bearer %OPENAI_API_KEY%" ^
  -d '{ ^
     "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo", ^
     "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "Say this is a test!"}], ^
     "temperature": 0.7 ^
   }'
```

And Cmd returned the error  reply below:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "We could not parse the JSON body of your request. (HINT: This likely means you aren't using your HTTP library correctly. The OpenAI API expects a JSON payload, but what was sent was not valid JSON. If you have trouble figuring out how to fix this, please contact us through our help center at help.openai.com.)",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": null,
        "code": null
    }
}
```

I can't find the error on the JSON body.I used the examples from Openai's documention.

After solving the format problem，the command is as below：

```
curl  -x 127.0.0.1:33210 https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions^
-H "Content-Type: application/json" ^
-H "Authorization: Bearer %OPENAI_API_KEY%" ^
-d "{"model": "gpt-3.5-turbo", "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "Say this is a test!"}], "temperature": 0.7 }"
```

but a problem remains:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "We could not parse the JSON body of your request. (HINT: This likely means you aren't using your HTTP library correctly. The OpenAI API expects a JSON payload, but what was sent was not valid JSON. If you have trouble figuring out how to fix this, please contact us through our help center at help.openai.com.)",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": null,
        "code": null
    }
}
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
curl: (3) bad range specification in URL position 12:
messages: [{role: user, content: Say
```

It seems that the curl doesn't package all the sentance which I wish to package, I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the `^` characters you parse in your JSON. The JSON data is parsed as a string, so we don't need the newline characters. A valid JSON command would be

```
curl -x 127.0.0.1:33210 https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions^
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" ^
  -H "Authorization: Bearer %OPENAI_API_KEY%" ^
  -d '{"model": "gpt-3.5-turbo", "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "Say this is a test!"}], "temperature": 0.7 }'
```

**EDIT**

The format problem is caused by using double quotes (") instead of single quotes (') around the JSON body. In [this link](https://reqbin.com/req/c-dwjszac0/curl-post-json-example), the following can be found in the first paragraph:

> JSON data is passed as a string. Double quotes in JSON must be escaped with the backslash "\ " on Windows computers.

In your case, that means that the data parsed after the data switch `-d` should be formatted as follows:

```
-d '{"model": "gpt-3.5-turbo", "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "Say this is a test!"}], "temperature": 0.7 }'
```

Note the single quotes around the whole JSON body, but the double quotes around the properties and values!

Comment: Thanks for your help!Although I have fixed the JSON format problem, the error still remains. I have update the question, and I wish you can spare time to read it again.

Comment: I edited my answer. Hopefully this works!